# zref not working for align environment

Tags: cross-referencing, align, amsmath, zref

I use `zref`, but the numbers are not correctly displayed for align environments (they are for equation, though).

example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{zref}
\usepackage{zref-user}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{a}
    \begin{align}
        a \zlabel{eq:a} \\
        b \zlabel{eq:b}
    \end{align}
    test: \zref{eq:a}, \zref{eq:a}
    \begin{equation}
        c \zlabel{eq:c}
    \end{equation}
    test2: \zref{eq:c}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I need the `zref` package since I want to reference other subfiles.

Also: figure references don't seem to work at all.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `\numberwithin` has nothing to do with the issue, so I removed it from your question. The output is exactly the same.

Comment: The issue isn't limited to instances of `align` environments -- it crops us with `gather` environments as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## First question: Environments of package `amsmath`

The environments of `amsmath` process the contents twice. The first run measures the width and the second run sets the equations. Also, they support `\notag` and friends. The is that the support of `\label` is quite hard-wired into the
environments. Other label as `\zlabel` are not supported.

A (crude) workaround:

1. Use of `\label` inside the  environments of package `amsmath`.
2. Import of the `\label`s as `\zlabels` via `zref-xr`.
3. Then the imported labels can be accessed by `\zref` with or without
   prefix, specified in the second step.

Example with prefix:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{zref}
\usepackage{zref-user}
\usepackage{zref-xr}

\zexternaldocument*[self:]{\jobname}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{a}
    \begin{align}
        a \label{eq:a} \\
        b \label{eq:b}
    \end{align}
    test: \zref{self:eq:a}, \zref{self:eq:b}
    \begin{equation}
        c \zlabel{eq:c}
    \end{equation}
    test2: \zref{eq:c}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

## Second question: Figure references

References for `\caption`s in `figure`s or `table`s work as expected:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{zref}
\usepackage{zref-user}

\begin{document}
\chapter{a}
\begin{figure}[h]% "h" as exception to get a smaller image for TeX.SX.
  \caption{Figure caption}
  \zlabel{fig:caption}
\end{figure}
Test: \zref{fig:caption}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative method for setting `\zlabel`s in `align`, and any other math environment of `amsmath`.  The idea is to let `amsmath` store `\label` as it usually does, but make it set both a regular `\label` and a `\zlabel` when actually setting the label. This can be achieved by redefining `\ltx@label` which is the macro responsible for the actual label setting in `amsmath`. The only  care to take here is to use the internal `\zref@label` for the task, since `\zlabel` renders itself no-op when `\label` is set to `\@gobble`, which is precisely the case in the `multline` environment.  Finally, if you happen to be using `hyperref` you should ensure your redefinition will not be overwritten by its call of `nameref`.  With that in hand, you *use* the regular `\label` in the environment, but both labels get defined (with the same name, with is not a problem, since the label systems are independent).

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[user]{zref}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\AddToHook { begindocument }
  {
    \@ifdefinable\myold@ltx@label{\let\myold@ltx@label\ltx@label}
    \newcommand*{\mybothlabels}[1]{%
      \myold@ltx@label{#1}%
      \zref@wrapper@babel\zref@label{#1}%
    }
    \renewcommand*{\ltx@label}[1]{\mybothlabels{#1}}
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter}
\begin{align}
  a \label{eq:a} \\
  b \label{eq:b}
\end{align}
test: \zref{eq:a}, \ref{eq:a}, \zref{eq:b}, \ref{eq:b}
\begin{equation}
  c \label{eq:c}
\end{equation}
test2: \zref{eq:c}, \ref{eq:c}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @UlrichDiez Thanks for the suggestion. I agree that usually that is the correct procedure. I just happen to have checked exactly what `\ltx@label` looks like, and who defines it. So I did some of the work `\renewcommand` would do for me. Besides `nameref` does exactly `\let\ltx@label\label`, so I'm following.

Comment: Well, you should tell that to the author of `nameref`  ;-)  Furthermore, it *knows* it is redefining an existing macro defined by someone else, since it is an internal macro to `amsmath`. It is just providing support for amsmath and hyperref to get along.

Comment: @UlrichDiez Anyway, I guess you are right, no harm in spreading good practices. Specially considering the diversity of the public here at TeX.SX. I edited for more "civil" procedures. Thanks for suggesting.