# What is a robust user-defined way to define cross-references and adjunct values that work inside and outside environments?

Tags: tcolorbox, etoolbox, zref, varioref

This question is a follow-up on these two

- [Why does \zifrefundefined fail on tcolorbox reference?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/633677/why-does-zifrefundefined-fail-on-tcolorbox-reference)
- [\@nameuse fails on definition within tcolorbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/633679/nameuse-fails-on-definition-within-tcolorbox)

What I want to achieve:

- I want to have an environment, e.g. [tcolorbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox), in which I have
- a way to define some kind of label that works with `\vref` or similar apporaches for having cross-references working back and forth, i.e. order **must not** matter
- a way to define additional variables connected to the label, something like `<label-name>@definition`
- I need to be able to check whether a certain label variable is available
- The approach must be stable against position in text, especially work inside or outside of environments

What I have learned so far:

##### zref

- `zref` works outside of environments like a charm. You can use `\zref@newprop`, `\zref@setcurrent`, `\zref@extractdefault` and `\zref@labelbyprops` to achieve astonishing results. `\zifrefundefined` helps top make your compilation run through even when something is missing.
- `zref` does not work within environments. I would appreciate something like `zref` but working within environments.

##### etoolbox

- `etoolbox` (which has only a documentation that works for very experienced [La]TeX users) is **totally robust with environments**. Using `\csgdef` and `\csuse` brings you very far.
- I am missing the complement feature of `\zifrefundefined`, but that is probably me not understanding the docs
- `etoolbox` has a caveat: order matters. Things have to be defined before first use.

##### Summary

I need the robustness for environments of `etoolbox` combined with the robustness of `zref` with regard to order of occurrence. Here's my testbed:

```latex
\documentclass[
  a4paper,
  11pt,
  parskip=half
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[nospace]{varioref}
\usepackage[pdfencoding=unicode, psdextra]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage[user]{zref}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\tcbuselibrary{breakable}

\DeclareNewTOC[
  category=float,
  float,% declares floating environment eq
  floatpos=ht,
  nonfloat,% declares non-floating environment eq-
  listname={Some Items},
  name=TM,
  tocentrystyle=tocline,
  tocentrylevel:=table,
  tocentryindent:=table,
  tocentrynumwidth:=table,
  type=MySpecialEnvFloat,
]{ltm}

\newtcolorbox[
    auto counter,
    crefname={TM}{TMs}]{MyBox}[2][]{
    title={TM\,\thetcbcounter: #2},
    #1}
  
\newcounter{MySpecialEnvCounter}

    
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\zref@newprop{Definition}{}

\newcommand{\MySpecialEnv}[4]{%
    \refstepcounter{MySpecialEnvCounter}%

    % etoolbox
    \csgdef{#1@Definition}{#2}

    % 
    \zlabel{#1}
    \zref@setcurrent{Definition}{#2}

    \begin{MyBox}[label={#1}]{#2}
        \addcontentsline{ltm}{section}{TM\,\theMySpecialEnvCounter: #2}

        Some text
        \tcblower
        #4
    \end{MyBox}
}%  
\makeatother

\listofMySpecialEnvFloats

\MySpecialEnv{test-id}{Something that looks like a summary}{-}{
    sdjoajhsja sijaoihs siahskah

    Nameuse: \@nameuse{test-id-2@Definition}

    Csname: \emph{\csname test-id-2@Definition\endcsname}

    % Order matters for etoolbox, so this one will fail
    Etoolbox: \csuse{test-id-2@Definition}
}

\MySpecialEnv{test-id-2}{Yet another summary}{-}{
    asjajsaj sakjskaj sjkajs
}

\subsection{varioref test}

\textbf{Varioref test}: Reference to \vref{test-id} and \vref{test-id-2},
\textbf{Pageref test}: \vpageref{test-id-2}

\subsection{Cref Test}

\cref{test-id}  \cpageref{test-id}

\subsection{etoolbox}

\makeatletter

A \csuse{test-id-2@Definition}

% How do I test for test-id-2 to bne defined?
B \ifdef{test-id-2}{\csuse{test-id-2@Definition}}{test-id-2 DOES NOT EXIST}

C \csuse{test-id-4@Definition}

D \ifdef{test-id-4}{\csuse{test-id-4@Definition}}{test-id-4 DOES NOT EXIST}

\makeatother

\subsection{zifrefundefined}

% Not robust against environments
\makeatletter
\zifrefundefined{test-id}{\nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries??}}{
    \zref@extractdefault{#1}{Definition}{}
}
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think that you neither really understand zref nor etoolbox and that it would better if you state your real problem instead of showing your half working tries to implement something.

Comment: I find this rather harsh. If I would understand any of those packages I probably would not be forced to ask here (which is the main reason for SO's existence). I tried to formulate my problem in text form and find it pretty clear what I want to achieve. And I show code that fails. If zref can work within environments (this is where the problem started for me) then I am happy to learn about it. AFAICS there are at least 5 different ways in LateX to get cross-refs and user-defined vars up and running and none really is straight forward nor are the docs for the faint-hearted to say the least.

Comment: Also since 20 years I trotally don't get why completely orthogonal things like user-defined key-value pairs and any kind of environments are such a mess.

Comment: Answers like this one make me think my hope is futile: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/402297/144487

Comment: well just in case you don't know: I'm one of the current maintainer of zref and I know quite well how it works and can even extend it in case it misses something.  But as  long I have no idea what you are actually trying to achieve I can't help you (the answer of Heiko about align is not really relevant as your code doesn't load amsmath).

Comment: Could you please explain what is unclear in the example/question above? I cross-checked everything and have absolutely no idea why the question remains unclear. E.g. make zref work **within** tcolorbox

Comment: Woukld it help if I post another question containing only the zref stuff?

Comment: you are not explaining *why* you use zref.  It is not clear if you are using the right tool.

Comment: I am so sorry. I have a typo (copy paste error) in my MNWE above: `#1` outside a macro instead of `test-id` and somehow `\zref@labelbyprops` got also lost.

Answer (score 0):

Markus, as far as I can see, you have two errors in your MWNE:

1. You have a typo in `\zref@extractdefault{#1}{Definition}{}`: I think `#1` should be replaced by `test-id`
2. Probably a code reduction accident: You forgot to register your variables with `\zref@labelbyprops`, **therefore `zref` appears as if it is not suitable for environments, but it is**. So your assumption about `zref` is wrong.

Here is a MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[
  a4paper,
  11pt,
  parskip=half
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[nospace]{varioref}
\usepackage[pdfencoding=unicode, psdextra]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=blue}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage[user]{zref}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\tcbuselibrary{breakable}

\DeclareNewTOC[
  category=float,
  float,% declares floating environment eq
  floatpos=ht,
  nonfloat,% declares non-floating environment eq-
  listname={Some Items},
  name=TM,
  tocentrystyle=tocline,
  tocentrylevel:=table,
  tocentryindent:=table,
  tocentrynumwidth:=table,
  type=MySpecialEnvFloat,
]{ltm}

\newtcolorbox[
    auto counter,
    crefname={TM}{TMs}]{MyBox}[2][]{
    title={TM\,\thetcbcounter: #2},
    #1}
  

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\referToMySpecialEnv}[1]{
    \zifrefundefined{#1}{\nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries??}}{
        \hyperref[#1]{\zref@extractdefault{#1}{ID}{}: 
        \emph{\zref@extractdefault{#1}{Definition}{}}} \vpageref{#1}
    }
}    
\makeatother
    
    
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\zref@newprop{Definition}{}
\zref@newprop{ID}{}

\newcommand{\MySpecialEnv}[4]{%

    \begin{MyBox}[label={#1}]{#2}
        \zref@setcurrent{Definition}{#2}%
        \zref@setcurrent{ID}{TM\,\thetcbcounter}
        \zref@labelbyprops{#1}{Definition, ID}
        \addcontentsline{ltm}{section}{TM\,\thetcbcounter: #2}
        Some text
        \tcblower
        #4
    \end{MyBox}
}%  
\makeatother

\listofMySpecialEnvFloats

\MySpecialEnv{test-id}{Something that looks like a summary}{-}{
    Here is a cross-reference to
    % Works like a charm within the box!
    \referToMySpecialEnv{test-id-2}
}

\MySpecialEnv{test-id-2}{Yet another summary}{-}{
    Here is a cross-reference to
    % Works like a charm within the box!
    \referToMySpecialEnv{test-id}
}

\subsection{varioref test}

\textbf{Varioref test}: Reference to \vref{test-id} and \vref{test-id-2},
\textbf{Pageref test}: \vpageref{test-id-2}

\subsection{Cref Test}

\cref{test-id}  \cpageref{test-id}

\subsection{zifrefundefined}

% Works outside in the wild
Let us check \referToMySpecialEnv{test-id} and \referToMySpecialEnv{test-id-2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Alright. Looks like you solved your own problem. As for the question, I suggest that you  **explain, as text outside the code block** (as comment inside the code block is hard to spot), **what output do you expect from the test and why**.  There's a comment such as "*Not robust against environments*" in the code, but from a quick read of the code I can't tell what does it mean or what output do you expect. (by the way no need to talk "as if you were someone else" in a self-answer...)