Cleveref, biblatex and automatic equation numbering
I would like to use biblatex for the bibliography, cleveref for clever references, and a package for automatic equation numbering such as autonum. Unfortunately, autonum is incompatible with biblatex. A popular alternative to autonum is the mathtools package with the option \mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs}. However, this solution is incompatible with cleveref.
Is there a solution to this problem?
Minimal (non-)working example:
% !BIB program = biber
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric, citestyle=ieee, sorting=ynt]{biblatex}
\usepackage{autonum}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}\label{chap:intro}
\begin{align}
a & = b\\
c &= d\label{eq:test}
\end{align}
Equation~\eqref{eq:test} in \cref{chap:intro} states that...

\end{document}


You should always show the example with the problem, not the example, where you've commented the problematic line!

You can use mathtools and package zref-clever instead of cleveref:
% !BIB program = biber
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs,showmanualtags}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric, citestyle=ieee,sorting=ynt]{biblatex}
\usepackage{zref-clever}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}\label{chap:intro}
\begin{align}
  a & = b\\
  c &= d\label{eq:test}\\
  e &= f\label{eq:ef}% Note: Don't use \zlabel here!  
\end{align}
Equation~\eqref{eq:test} in \zcref{chap:intro}
together with \zcref{eq:ef} % \zcref supports showonlyrefs
states that \dots
\end{document}



Thanks for your solution! This was exactly what I was looking for. Indeed, I was referring to autonum instead of autoref.

Hoh! someone noticed that! It makes me glad.  :-) +1. But it is actually even nicer. zref-clever has full support for showonlyrefs, meaning you can use \zcref[S]{eq:test} instead of Equation~\eqref{eq:test}.

@gusbrs I tested it, but also changed \label into \zlabel and then it doesn't work. I've now tested with \label instead of \zlabel and it works. So it seems the experimental state of zref-clever still makes sense … I've extended the example to show it (and also added a comment, that \label instead of \zlabel has to be used).

@gusbrs BTW: This is not my first answer with zref-clever instead of cleveref as possible solution. For me, the experimental status is the only reason not to prefer the package in principle. In some long-term projects, stability is simply more important. A cleveref option comparable to the natbib option of biblatex would also be useful for switching experiments, for example.

@cabohah This has little to do with the experimental status of the package. amsmath display math environments is the main place where \label instead of \zlabel is mandatory instead of just "recommended" (see amsmath how-to in the manual). The reason is how amsmath handles \labels in display math environments and there's little zref-clever (or zref) can do about it (see see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/402297 and https://github.com/ho-tex/zref/issues/4). Btw, I've seen the other answer too, it is nice to see people catching up to some of the niceties of the package. :-)

Ah, I forgot to mention on thing. There's a little price to rely on \zcref with showonlyrefs: for technical reasons, \zcref needs one more compilation run than \eqref to converge. So, since \eqref already requires 3, we need then 4...
